# 'Seven-dollar questions'

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

In *Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance*, this phrase was used:

> "hold up on all those wonderful seven-dollar questions."

Does seven-dollar questions mean silly, useless questions?

Comment: There being so few hits for this on a Google search, and no authoritative linguistic references that I've come across, it's got to be regarded as a nonce expression and thus off-topic on a site dedicated to (reasonably) standard English usage. Though your guess is probably correct.

Comment: clicking ads ??

Comment: When this book was written, in the early 1970’s, $7.00 was not a small amount. Taking inflation into account, it would be almost $35.00 in today’s money. So unlikely to mean a silly or useless question.

Comment: I'm tempted to agree with both Edwin and James and yet it seems the context is all-important.

Not remembering Zen and The Art…, I have to ask for the context, and your research about that, and your conclusion from that…

Comment: In my densely urbanized vicinity, $7 is today a trifle.

Comment: @jtheletter When I was a child (in the 1980s), I was an avid reader and frequently used what my family called "25-cent words" when I spoke. When I got to high school, we would call them SAT words. Nowadays, I might not bend over to pick up a quarter. But my grandparents, who grew up during the Great Depression, consider quarters to significant worth. Inflation and timeperiod should be considered.

Comment: That’s why I said “today”.

Answer (score 1):

Robert Persig's *Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance* was published in 1974.

At that time, game shows like [The $64,000 Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_$64,000_Question) and its equivalents from the late fifties would still have been fresh in his mind (he was born in 1928).  In particular, the scandals surrounding these shows, where some contestants were given advance knowledge of the questions and answers, would have resonated strongly with Persig's concepts of *quality* and *authenticity*, which are central to the book.

A $7.00 question is trivial in comparison with a $64.00 question, $128.00 question, and so on up the game show ladder. But I think Persig is hinting that the apparently greater questions deserve more than passing scrutiny, and that the apparently smaller questions, *truthfully asked and answered*, are actually of greater value.

Comment: Plausible. But why 7? Why not 2?